# How exactly do I null my metal detector coils?

Tags: inductance, coil, detector

I've finally started work on my metal detector project and after a fair start, I'm a bit stuck.

The circuit is based almost entirely on the buccaneer VLF circuit to be found [here](http://www.geotech1.com/cgi-bin/pages/common/index.pl?page=metdet&file=/projects/buccaneer/index.dat).
I've made some alterations, I've upped the voltage to 9V and made the necessary adjustments to account for that.  I've also increased the coil diameter to 20cm (the original was 11cm), but I've kept the inductances more or less the same (my coils measure 2.9mH, whereas the original was somewhere in the region of 2.3mH).  With the Tx and Rx circuit built (on the breadboard - yes, I know it's not the best, but I didn't want to commit to a full build just yet) and the Tx oscillator up and running, I tried nulling the Rx coil.  I must have spent hours trying to get near where I thought I should be at (millivolt level) without much success.

In the screenshots below, I set the p-p Tx voltage at about 40V by trimming R6.  This is considerably less than the expected output of the original circuit (80V on my simulations) and yet the Rx coild is showing just over 2V p-p (1.8Vrms), which is certainly a far cry from the millivolt level I was expecting.

The give away here, is that in the original circuit the pre-amp gain is set to be roughly 10.  When I tried that kind of gain, my signal railed badly, so I reduced the gain to 5 but it's still clipping.

So, my first question is this:  **just exactly what should I expect when I "null" my coils and do my results look normal?**

Secondly, I wasn't expecting a perfect induced signal but the Rx coil has these **annoying witches hats that appear at twice the operating frequency**.  If you look really closely at the Tx signal you can just make out the glitch that may be coupled into the Rx coil, but I'm not sure.  **What can be causing this?**  One thing to note is that the "hats" move around the signal as I squeeze the coils to try to null them.  It's really screwing up my Rx signal.

I know there's a lot to take in here and if you need more info I'll post that up.

**UPDATE:** Incidentally, for those who'd like to know more about the Tx Oscillator, see this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259527/questions-regarding-metal-detector-tx-coil-circuit)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why did you turn one of the transistors upside down, compared to the original schematic? You can see distortion on the first scope waveform which are the likely cause of the distortion products on the second.

Comment: Hi Brian, which one? It's probably a transcription error I checked the actual circuit pretty thoroughly.

Comment: I tend to document my circuits and notes, etc in TinyCad - just out of habit.

Comment: Yep, I see it now...the push-pull pair right?  Let me fix that up. Tks.  Good eyes;-)

Comment: My best guess re the distortion was that the Tx oscillator was being fed (essentially) by a square wave and that maybe (total guess) that some higher frequency harmonics were creeping in?  But, I don't fully understand that stuff, so that's a total guess!

Comment: Shouldn't the receive coil be earthed - as it stands it's just a floating loop with a single point connection to an input. BTW, which transistor was upside down and have you fixed the pictures or is it still distorting? Ditto the transmit coil - you won't get any power through that coil as it stands.

Comment: @Andy the circuit schematic is fixed now, the "actual" circuit was fine.  Earthed? The Rx coil is wired at both ends, but I haven't wrapped it in foil if that's what you mean.  There seems to be some debate as to whether you really need to do this.  What's your opinion?

Comment: @Andy hell you're right! I completely missed that in the original circuit and I've checked the actual circuit and it's floating.  God bless your eyes!

Comment: There are earths needed on both coil circuits. Magenta electronics eh? (the link in your question). I've actually been there hee hee. Let me know when you get this straightened up so I can give advice on screening and nulling (a bit of a speciality of mine).

Comment: You guys are worth your weight in gold! I grounded the Rx coil as Andy suggested and it works like a charm! Thankyou.

Comment: Shall I make that an answer or are you going to still modify the question in some way?

Comment: @Andy by all means make that an answer, I won't be modifying the question although I'd still like to hear your opinion on the shielding.

Comment: Hi could you please tell me how did you simulate the coupling coils in the software?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think at the time I used an online air-core inductance calculator to get a "ballpark" inductance value.  The instructions call for 100 turns of 28swg gauge wire with a diameter of 110mm.  These days I'd probably just wind ten turns and measure it with an inductance meter and then extrapolate.

Comment: I typically only use the simulator to help me understand how a circuit works and for me it's not critical that the component values are exact.  I don't believe I modeled the "coupling" between the coils and instead just went and built it.  Personally, I would find it difficult to simulate the action of an approaching metal object.

Comment: I would get rid of the steel nails in your clips holding down your coil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is this: -

[image]

In case you can't read my red writing, you are missing a connection from the receive coil to earth.

As for screening, yes, you need it to avoid the search head picking up silver foil confectionary wrappers and other useless bits of stuff you want to ignore. Salty conductive soil is also an annoying problem that is largely solved by a coil screen.

Balancing - if you are still having problems, try a little bit of ferrite core placed adjacent to your coils to get the best "balance minimum". Then, try a little piece of non-magnetic stainless steel to try and take the minimum even lower.

Ferrite is non conductive so you can use it to basically balance the inductive artefacts. SS is good because it's quite resistive and although it will upset the inductive balance (due to eddy current induction) those eddy currents will be quite resistive in nature. Thin bits of tin foil (basically what you see in a cigarette packet) might also be useful for helping to balance the coils.

So, messing around with ferrite and SS (and or tin foil), will give you an idea where you could get by mechanically bending the coils a bit this way or that way. But you can always solidly glue down a piece of ferrite in the search head to avoid all this messing around.

The screening/balancing information provided in this answer is not anyone's IP - I learnt it designing metal detectors for food/pharmaceutical product lines.

Comment: If I get a chance I'll update this question with images of what a balanced receiver signal looks like, since I noticed that there isn't a whole lot of that around.

Answer (score 0):

TX coil connects to detector and RX does not.
The ends of the RX coil are directly connected to the millivoltmeter.
Leave the detector in operation and slowly move the RX spool until you get the least voltage, in my case it was 0.04 mv, but I read somewhere that it was ok and 15 mv.
It should protect both coils with a metal foil, but so that the foils between the spools do not touch and that both are connected by cable to the mass of the detector. I use old USB cables because they have an external protection I use for that.
on the spools leave a small slit (5-10 mm).
I am nullifying this and I made my probe and I have detection for 1e-35cm.
Excuse me for bad English
Please see the picture attached
[image]